# Как можно список с датами преобразовать в нужный формат?

Tags: python, python-2.x

Всем привет.

Сижу с проблемой преобразования дат из списка в нужный формат.

Существует список, в котором хранятся даты формата `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S - ('2017-11-03 00:00:00', '2017-11-03 00:00:00', '2017-11-03 00:00:00', '2017-11-03 00:00:00', '2017-11-03 00:00:00')`. Все эти даты мне надо преобразовать в формат `%d-%m-%y`.

У меня получается это сделать с одной датой 

`db_date = '2017-11-03 00:00:00'
date = str(db_date)
x = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%d-%m-%y')`,
но не получается проделать это, когда в списке хранится столько значений.

Может, кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким ?
И как потом все преобразованные даты можно будет сравнить с другой переменной ?(т.е. проверить соответствие полученных дат с нужной)

Comment: преобразованные в такой формат (`%d-%m-%y`) даты (в виде строк) можно будет нормально сравнивать только если преобразовывать каждую из сравниваемых дат в объект типа `datetime` или в ваш исходный формат. Поэтому стоит либо преобразовать в объекты типа `datetime` либо оставить в таком формате даты (чтобы сравнение правильно работало)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас же есть решение, можно перебрать список, заменив значения на нужные Вам, либо сложить их в новый список.

```
s = ['2017-11-03 00:00:00', '2017-11-03 00:00:00', '2017-11-03 00:00:00', '2017-11-03 00:00:00', '2017-11-03 00:00:00']
for i,w in enumerate(s):
    s[i] = datetime.datetime.strptime(w, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%d-%m-%y')
```

Да и сравнивать их можно:

```
if s[0] > '02-11-17':    pass
```

Comment: Отличный вариант сравнения дат - если конечный результат не важен: `'30-01-01' > '02-11-17' == True` ;-)

Comment: Упс) недоглядел, там же строки так и остались

Comment: Огромное спасибо ! 
Пока идёт туго с циклами.